# How does a base class know the attributes of it's derived class

Tags: c++

Hi I'm having trouble with this problem logically and need some help. What I have set up is a base class named 'objects' and a derived class named 'robot'. I've created an instance of the 'robot' in another class 'game', which includes 'robot' (through pointers). So the line of code I have for that is

```
robot* rob = new robot(int x, int y)
```

where position is an attribute of the class robot. In my 'objects' class I have Get and Set functions for the x and y coordinate, as the x and y coordinates are set as private.

Now, I understand that class 'robot' can access and update it's own x and y coordinates. Is it possible to include and even change x and y in the 'objects' class? The way I was thinking on doing this was to create a member of 'game' in 'objects' and change the position of 'robot' in 'objects'. But as 'rob' is passed as a reference to 'objects', can it still change the x and y coordinates? Even after then, how does 'game' know the new position of 'rob'?

EDIT: solved by user below

Comment: Please edit your post to include the contents of your `objects` and `robot` classes.

Comment: if `robot` derives from `objects` and only `objects` has `x` and `y`, the `robot` only has once instance of `x` and `y`. To answer the title question - it does not

Comment: A base knows nothing about those that derive from it. Think about the non-causal behaviour that would require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base class is an abstraction of the more more specialized classes that follow. As a result a base knows nothing, and has no need to know, about those that derive from it. All any class knows is itself and what the classes on which it is based make available to it.

In addition, the C++ build process makes it impossible to know all possible permutations of future child classes. It would have to know about code that may not have been written yet or be in other modules that may or may not be linked in later or at runtime.

To manipulate a base class's members through a subclass most of the time you don't have to do anything. For `public` and `protected` variables what's in the base class is accessible in the subclass. `private` data is off limits, as usual (but look up `friend`ship).

If the base class has an `int x`

```
x = 24;
```

will do the job for most cases.

This only becomes a problem if both the base and the subclass have a variable of the same name.

Time for some code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct object // using struct because it defaults to public access. 
              // This makes for a simpler example
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct robot:public object
{
    int x; // variable hides the x in object
    int y;

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "robot: " << x << ',' << object::x << '\n'; 
        // to access object's x we must ask for it explicitly
    }
};

struct betterrobot:public object
{
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "better robot: " << x << ',' << object::x << '\n';
    }
};
int main() {

    robot rob;
    rob.x = 24; // set robot's x
    rob.object::x = 42; // set object's x
    rob.print();

    betterrobot rob2;
    rob2.x = 24;
    rob2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> robot: 24,42
>
> better robot: 24,24

`Object` and `robot` have their own `x` and `y`. `object`'s `x` can be reached through `robot` by explicitly requesting it

```
rob.object::x = 42;
```

In the output, printing `x` and `object::x` gave different answers. If you only

```
rob.x = 24;
```

a smart compiler will scream at you for not initializing `object::x` as soon as it sees the `robot::print` method. If it doesn't, happy debugging!

This is something you rarely want to do because it wreaks havoc on the brain. You have two `x`s, and when you are working on polymprphic objects (Note: no polymorphic objects in example to keep things simple) it's really easy to screw up and set the wrong `x`. Don't do this unless there is no way to avoid it.

It is almost always better to inherit and use the base class's variable to avoid confusion. This is what `betterrobot` does. `betterrobot` only has `object`'s `x` and `y`. There is no possibility for confusion.

```
rob2.x = 24;
```

is all there is. In the output, printing `x` and `object::x` gave the same answer.

You can move `betterrobot` around like you can any other `object`. Functions in `object`, `move` for example can be used to move `betterrobot` around on the map. No special magic is required.

Comment: Very useful! THank you